# Left Outer Join Difference in SQL Server 2000 vs 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have below query similar to my query of SQL Server 2000. How to write it in newer version of 2012. Please ignore the result it will return. Please help me with the syntax.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Employee] e1, [Employee] e2, [Employee] e3
WHERE (e1.City = 'kolanter')
  AND (e1.employeeNumber *= e2.employeeNumber)
  AND (e1.EName *= e2.EName)
  AND (e1.Skill *= e2.Skill)

  AND (e2.City = 'Debrigart')
  AND (e2.employeeNumber *= e3.employeeNumber)
  AND (e2.EName *= e3.EName)
  AND (e2.Skill *= e3.Skill)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND e2.City = 'Debrigart' in the where kills the left
Need to have that as join condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    [Employee] e1
    LEFT JOIN
    [Employee] e2 ON e1.employeeNumber = e2.employeeNumber
                 AND e1.EName = e2.EName
                 AND e1.Skill = e2.Skill
                 AND e2.City = 'Debrigart'
    LEFT JOIN
    [Employee] e3 ON (e2.employeeNumber = e3.employeeNumber)
                 AND (e2.EName = e3.EName)
                 AND (e2.Skill = e3.Skill)
WHERE 
    e1.City = 'kolanter'
```

If this is a real query then that is that is a really messed up table
If employeeNumber, EName, and Skill repeat with different city that is a lot of repeated data

Comment: `AND e2.City = 'Debrigart' in the where kills the left` is a good point ;).

Comment: It will take some time for me to test it. will check and update accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    [Employee] e1
    LEFT JOIN
    [Employee] e2 ON e1.employeeNumber = e2.employeeNumber
                 AND e1.EName = e2.EName
                 AND e1.Skill = e2.Skill
    LEFT JOIN
    [Employee] e3 ON (e2.employeeNumber = e3.employeeNumber)
                 AND (e2.EName = e3.EName)
                 AND (e2.Skill = e3.Skill)
WHERE 
    (e1.City = 'kolanter')
    AND 
    (e2.City = 'Debrigart')
    --or for having all results form e1 that e2.city isnull
    --(ISNULL(e2.City, 'Debrigart') = 'Debrigart')
```

Comment: I think you need to bring e2.City = 'Debrigart' up into the join or you kill the left

Comment: No they are not the same.  With your syntax if there is a match on e1.City = 'kolanter' but no match on e2.City = 'Debrigart' the row will not be returned.

Comment: @Blam As you said `e2.City` will be `NULL` in that case and in the OP's question also it shouldn't show in result ;).

Comment: What part of row not returned is not clear?  Null value and no row are not the same.  That syntax turns that E2 into a regular join.